# How could one identify CSharpSyntaxNodes that are inside of #region and #if DEBUG directives using the CSharpSyntaxRewriter?

Tags: c#, .net, testing, extract, roslyn

I am trying to create a [`CSharpSyntaxRewriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpsyntaxrewriter?view=roslyn-dotnet-3.9.0) that can identify [`CSharpSyntaxNodes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpsyntaxnode?view=roslyn-dotnet-3.9.0) that fall between both `#region` and `#if DEBUG` preprocessor directives.

For example:
The [`ClassDeclarationSyntax`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.syntax.classdeclarationsyntax?view=roslyn-dotnet-3.9.0) nodes that should be identified are `InternalStaffTest`, `Utility`, `StaffTest`, and `StaffHelper`.

```
namespace Business
{
    public class Staff
    {
        int id;
        string name;

        public Staff(int id, string name)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public int Id()
        {
            return this.id;
        }

        public string Name()
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        public string GlobalId()
        {
            return $"gid:{this.id}:{this.name}";
        }

        #region Test
        #if DEBUG

        class InternalStaffTest
        {
             public void TestFieldToGetterMapping()
             {
                 // A test that relies on having access to the internals of the class, and uses
                 // the Utility class during the test.
             }
        }

        class Utility
        {
             public string GenerateRandomName()
             {
                // An example non-static utility method for the test.
             }
        }

        #endif
        #endregion
    }
}

#region Test
#if DEBUG

namespace Business.Test
{
    class StaffTest
    {
        public void TestId()
        {
            // A test that does not rely on having access to the internals of the class, but
            // uses the StaffHelper class to run.
        }
    }

    static class StaffHelper()
    {
        public static Staff NewStaff()
        {
            // An example static utility method for creating new staff for each test.
        }
    }
}

#endif
#endregion
```

I understand that the above code violates quite a few principles of quality software engineering, and is not good form - but the tool I am working on needs to operate on a significant amount of legacy code exactly like this. The nodes are then deleted, extracted, or left based on other factors that are outside of my control.

The initial approach was to simply try to identify the nodes by using the `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` and overriding the [`VisitClassDeclaration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpsyntaxrewriter.visitclassdeclaration?view=roslyn-dotnet-3.9.0#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_CSharp_CSharpSyntaxRewriter_VisitClassDeclaration_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_CSharp_Syntax_ClassDeclarationSyntax_) method and check if the class name ended in "Test" however this would mean that helper classes such as `StaffHelper` and `Utility` in the above example would be missed - even though they should have some sort of operation run on them.

The second approach then was to record the "state" of the rewriter, by overriding the [`VisitIfDirectiveTrivia`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpsyntaxrewriter.visitifdirectivetrivia?view=roslyn-dotnet-3.9.0#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_CSharp_CSharpSyntaxRewriter_VisitIfDirectiveTrivia_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_CSharp_Syntax_IfDirectiveTriviaSyntax_) and [`VisitRegionDirectiveTrivia`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.csharpsyntaxrewriter.visitregiondirectivetrivia?view=roslyn-dotnet-3.9.0#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_CSharp_CSharpSyntaxRewriter_VisitRegionDirectiveTrivia_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_CSharp_Syntax_RegionDirectiveTriviaSyntax_) methods to record when I had seen a `#region` and then a `#if DEBUG`, however this also was not sufficient as there are cases where the order is flipped.

I then tried to record when I had seen one or the other, and therefore I would know if a given `CSharpSyntaxNode` was within both a `#region` and a `#if DEBUG` if I had recorded that the rewriter had seen both of them. However this also did not work because the `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` is depth first, meaning it will visit the nodes I want to delete or extract before it visits the the nodes associated with the `#region` and `#if DEBUG`.

So the question is: given a depth first parser, is there any way to know if a certain syntax node is between two other syntax nodes. If not, while still using the `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` (because other parts of this tool use it and I have been directed to use it) is there a way for me to determine if the node being visited is inside of a `#region` and `#if DEBUG` preprocessor directive.